# Wordpress bootstrap menue with 3. level

Tags: sub-menu, dropdown, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 3 and a navbar as navigation. I have found this Code to create the menu, works like a charm:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_nav_menu_items/#comment-1609

But for now this code don't provide 3. level items.

I found this page to display the 3. level:
http://blog.inbytes.de/2015/11/responsive-multilevel-dropdown-menue-mit-bootstrap-3/

Can you help me to figure out the php part to show the 3. level items, too?

Regards
Peronia

EDIT:
My code:

```
function create_bootstrap_menu( $theme_location ) {
if ( ($theme_location) && ($locations = get_nav_menu_locations()) && isset($locations[$theme_location]) ) {

    $menu_list  = '<nav class="navbar navbar-default">' ."\n";
    $menu_list .= '<div class="container-fluid">' ."\n";
    $menu_list .= '<div class="navbar-header">' ."\n";
    $menu_list .= '<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">' ."\n";
    $menu_list .= '<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>' ."\n";
    $menu_list .= '<span class="icon-bar"></span>' ."\n";
    $menu_list .= '<span class="icon-bar"></span>' ."\n";
    $menu_list .= '<span class="icon-bar"></span>' ."\n";
    $menu_list .= '</button>' ."\n";
    $menu_list .= '</div>' ."\n";

    $menu_list .= '<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->';


    $menu = get_term( $locations[$theme_location], 'nav_menu' );
    $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);

    $menu_list .= '<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">' ."\n";
    $menu_list .= '<ul class="nav navbar-nav">' ."\n";

    foreach( $menu_items as $menu_item ) {
        if( $menu_item->menu_item_parent == 0 ) {

            $parent = $menu_item->ID;

            $menu_array = array();
//------------> here start the 2. lvl navigation
            foreach( $menu_items as $submenu ) {
                if( $submenu->menu_item_parent == $parent ) {
                    $bool = true;
                    $menu_array[] = '<li><a href="' . $submenu->url . '">' . $submenu->title . '</a></li>' ."\n";
                }
            }
            if( $bool == true && count( $menu_array ) > 0 ) {

                $menu_list .= '<li class="dropdown">' ."\n";
                $menu_list .= '<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">' . $menu_item->title . ' <span class="caret"></span></a>' ."\n";

                $menu_list .= '<ul class="dropdown-menu">' ."\n";
                $menu_list .= implode( "\n", $menu_array );
                $menu_list .= '</ul>' ."\n";
                $menu_list .= '</li>' ."\n";

            } else {
//------------> here ends the 2. lvl navigation 
//------------> here start the 1. lvl navigation 
                $menu_list .= '<li>' ."\n";
                $menu_list .= '<a href="' . $menu_item->url . '">' . $menu_item->title . '</a>' ."\n";
                $menu_list .= '</li>' ."\n";
            }
//------------> here ends the 1. lvl navigation
//------------> the 3. lvl is missing
        }

    }

    $menu_list .= '</ul>' ."\n";
    $menu_list .= '</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->' ."\n";
    $menu_list .= '</div><!-- /.container-fluid -->' ."\n";
    $menu_list .= '</nav>' ."\n";

} else {
    $menu_list = '<!-- no menu defined in location "'.$theme_location.'" -->';
}

echo $menu_list;
}
```

As i wrote in the comments, the 3. lvl navigation is missing. I don't know where to add.

Comment: please add you relevant code to the question, and explain exactly what is the issue you are facing. in your code

Comment: done, hope it suits your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to improve HTML template.

You may use this to get it working. You just need to improve your HTML [like this](http://bootsnipp.com/index.php/snippets/oPWaZ).

You may also try [multi-level-dropdown-menu](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-dropdown-menu-bs3).

Comment: Thanks, but the php file must check for the third lvl. When it exists load the improved HTML (your links are helpfull!). But when the item doesn't have a child the "normal" item must be loaded.
I need this php to check this.